# In hybris 1905 on adding custom folder and data folder, smartedit perspective is not coming like basic,advanced etc

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have moved custom and data folder for project created on hybris 6.0 to hybris 1905 but now hybris OOB features are not coming up i.e. in smartedit ,perspectives are not coming. I have included the extensions required to run smartedit in localextensions.xml but still it is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually have installed SmartEdit, please make sure you must install the smarteditaddon AddOn as follows and rebuild your system:

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames=smarteditaddon -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=<your_custom_storefront>
```

Refer [this document](https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1905/en-US/0955af7dd5154a8db28dfce327d8dae5.html).

Comment: can you check these addon files got copied in your storefront extension after the build?

Comment: Yes i have smarteditaddon installed in my storefront addon structure